# C# PDM addin : Not getting data card exact information for related file when changing state instead getting BOM

Tags: c#, add-in, solidworks

Actually i created one addin where whenever file state is change i want to fetch 'Data card' tab information.

- in following figure 1. (ex. its JPR-DKUS-A-01 ...02 etc..)
- But strange this is i am not getting it but actually what i get is BOM's last row's product 
  information (SCR-0039) (see figure 2) ..when i do state change on other file i am getting 
  proper data card information who don't have BOM. don't know why this is happening.

Figure :1
[data card tab's product information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEfLg.png)

Figure :2
[BOM information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmDFm.png)

C# Addin Code is like as below:

```
public void OnCmd(ref EdmCmd poCmd, ref EdmCmdData[] ppoData)
{
IEdmVault5 edmVault = poCmd.mpoVault as IEdmVault5;
IEdmFile7 aFile;
IEdmBom bom;
IEdmBomMgr bomMgr;
IEdmBomView bomView;
string str_b = "";

try
{
switch (poCmd.meCmdType)
{
case EdmCmdType.EdmCmd_PostState:



IEdmFile5 file = vault.GetFileFromPath(fileName, out IEdmFolder5 folder);

int ver = 0;
ver = file.CurrentVersion;

IEdmEnumeratorVariable8 EnumVarObj = default(IEdmEnumeratorVariable8);
EnumVarObj = (IEdmEnumeratorVariable8)file.GetEnumeratorVariable();

// Get configurations
EdmStrLst5 cfgList = default(EdmStrLst5);
cfgList = file.GetConfigurations();

IEdmPos5 pos = default(IEdmPos5);
pos = cfgList.GetHeadPosition();
string cfgName = null;

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> myDictDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

while (!pos.IsNull)
{

cfgName = cfgList.GetNext(pos);
object VarObj = null;

EnumVarObj.GetVar("PartNo", cfgName, out VarObj);
string VarVal = VarObj?.ToString();

EnumVarObj.GetVar("Description", cfgName, out VarObj);
string Description = VarObj?.ToString();

EnumVarObj.GetVar("Revision", cfgName, out VarObj);
string revision = VarObj?.ToString();

Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

values.Add("PartNo", VarVal);
values.Add("Revision", revision);
values.Add("Description", Description);


myDictDict.Add(cfgName, values);

}
}
}
}
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: Forum.solidworks.com is the best place to find an answer